# Insert casper javascript data to CSV file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to pass data from casper JS to CSV file I am currently using

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.write('test.csv', "name, title", "a");
fs.write('test.csv', name.trim()+","+title.trim(), "a");
```

this is inside a loop so there are many records

but printing to the CSV file is not inserting to a new row. It currently writes like this and I only want 2 columns on this

```
Name    Title
name1   name1    name2   title2    name3   title3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add linebreaks

```
fs.write('test.csv', name.trim()+","+title.trim()+"\n", "a");
```

---

CSVs vary, but all usually have four special chars,

- delimiter (the comma)
- escape char (usually `\`, use to escape the other special chars when used in the data
- line delimiter (usually `\n`, the newline character),
- wrapper, (usually quotes that wrap around each value)

So, if you really want a proper CSV you would do something like this.

```
function escapeCSVData(text){
    text = text.
        replace("\", "\\,"). // escape any escape chars
        replace(",", "\,"); // escape commas
    return '"'+text+'"'; // add quotes
}

fs.write('test.csv', escapeCSVData(name.trim())+","+escapeCSVData(title.trim())+"\n", "a");
```

I didn't test the above, but that should work for you.

**EDIT**

I just learned that commas are simply quoted, not escaped, so the function would actaully just look like this..

```
function escapeCSVData(text){
    return '"'+text+'"'; // add quotes
}
```

Comment: Your solution is cleaner than my quick typing. I'll just add that CSVs are not simply comma-separated -- you need to escape data that might contain delimiters -- it is not enough to simply add the `+","+`

Comment: assuming there is some ambiguity, you're right, but the sample data given doesn't require anything to be escaped.

Comment: how do I escape the comma on string though? I'm having problems with it now

Comment: can you post a snippet of the data that is causing problems so I can tell you the best way to do it?

Comment: considering the string "Illinois, Chicago" there's a comma it gets treated as 2 columns in the CSV

Comment: check the edit i just posted. let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the "\" on the first replace should be regex I tried the string but it prompts an error  itried text.replace(/\\/g,"\\,")

Answer (score 2):

Add a line break after each write

```
fs.write('test.csv', "name, title\n", "a");
```

**edit**

Please note that although this solves your new line (row) problem, CSVs are more than just adding commas between entries. If any of your data contains a comma, you will need to escape them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

There are a few libraries for note, like https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv#readme -- but if you know absolutely how your data is going to behave, you can go on with your solution.