# Casper JS data to CSV file dealing with comma

Tags: javascript, csv, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm saving casper JS data to CSV file but how do escape comma so that it would not be included as a new column in the CSV?

example

```
var data = "asdf, fff";
fs = require('fs');
fs.write("test.csv", "Data \n", "a");
fs.write("test.csv", data, "a");
```

This:

```
     Data
     asdf         fff
```

Should be:

```
     Data
     asdf, fff
```

NOTE: the variable data can have comma or not

Answer (score 1):

in discussion here [Insert casper javascript data to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928005/insert-casper-javascript-data-to-csv-file/35928092#35928092)

comma should be escaped using:

```
function escapeCSVData(text){
    text = text.
        replace("/\\/g", "\\,"). // escape any escape chars
        replace(",", "\,"); // escape commas
    return '"'+text+'"'; // add quotes
}
```

I swapped the code from the link from "\" to /\/g this is the proper way to target a backslash